# port conflict between Hadoop and python

Tags: python, hadoop, port, conflict

I am installing Hadoop 2.5.0 on a Ubuntu 12.04 cluster, 64-bit. At the end of the instructions I type `$ jps` on the master node and do not get a NameNode. I checked the Hadoop logs and found:

> BindException error stating :9000 is already in use.

`$ netstat -a -t --numeric-ports -p | grep :9000` returns that python is listening on this port. It appears I need to move python 2.7 to another port. How do I move python?

Followed the command below, the pid=2346.

> $ ps -p 2346
>
> PID TTY    TIME CMD
>
> 2346 ? 01:28:13 python

Tried second command:

> $ ps -lp 2346
>
> F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
>
> 4 S     0  2346     1  0  80   0 - 332027 poll_s ?       01:28:30 python

more detail:

> $ ps -Cp 2346
>
> PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
>
> 2346 ?        Ssl   88:34 /usr/lib/cmf/agent/build/env/bin/python /usr/lib/cmf/agent/src/cmf/agent.py --package_dir /usr/lib/cmf

It appears a failed Cloudera Hadoop distribution installation has not been removed. It installed python 2.7 automatically. Not sure what else is automatically running. Will attempt to uninstall python 2.7.

Comment: Its not Python, its a script you have running. Type `netstat -anp | grep 9000` to see the PID of the script.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear a program written in python is using port 9000 and not python2.7 itself.

You need to track down this program and then work out how to config it to listen on a different port. You could use this command to get the full details of the process listening on port 9000

```
netstat -a -t --numeric-ports -p | grep :9000 | awk '{print $7}' | sed -e 's/\/.*//'  | xargs echo ps -lp
```

Comment: Thanks. The suggested command pid=2346. $ ps -p 2346 yields         PID TTY    TIME    CMD
 2346 ?   01:28:13 python

Comment: You want the -l flag on the ps so you can see the name of the python program.

Answer (score 0):

It appears Cloudera installed python 2.7. This was removed / replace with python 3.2.
The $jps command on Hadoop now returns the expected results including NameNode.